# In a SQL request, how to find all the records that have digits in the last part of the string (after last whitespace)

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, phpmyadmin

Thanks if someone can help.

In my table, I have a street column, and a number column. But for some records, the number of the house is at the end of the street name in the street column, separated by a whitespace.

From a request in phpmyadmin, **I would like to remove the last block of the street column (after last whitespace) if this block contains any digit and put this block in the number column**.

I entered that request in phpmyadmin to just find those records.

```
SELECT `street`,`number` 
FROM `map` 
WHERE `street` REGEXP '[\r\n\t\f\v ][0-9]+ ^[\r\n\t\f\v ]'
```

but the request is not complete because it doesn't take only the last block, and because it's also not removing the substring and putting into the number column.

**Examples for how it should work: (street column, number column) :**

- `('Rue van Malder 47B', '-1')` becomes `('Rue van Malder', '47B')`
- `('Rue des 2 Arbres 511B', '-1')` becomes `('Rue des 2 Arbres', '511B')` ->only last block with one ore more digits moves from street to number column
- `('place du 4 Août', '1')` stays `('place du 4 Août', '1')` because the digit '4' is not in the last block
- `('751 2nd St', '-1')` stays `('751 2nd St', '-1')` for same reason than just above

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You can't use `^` in the middle of a regular expression. It matches the beginning of the string, so it only makes sense at the beginning.

Comment: Will `('Rue van Malder B47', '-1')` become `('Rue van Malder', 'B47')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exactly found the request I was needed with your help Gordon Linoff and some searches on google and I'll explain it here for eventual future help:

UPDATE map
SET `number` = substring_index(`street`, ' ', -1), 
`street` = LEFT(`street`, LENGTH(`street`) - LENGTH(substring_index(`street`, ' ', -1))-1)
WHERE `street` REGEXP '[\r\n\t\f\v ][0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*$'

So first, I update in the 'map' table 2 columns: number and street:

-number is found with the last part of the string from the last space
-street is found by replacing it with a substring removing to the whole 'street' string, the length of the number part (part we juste founded before)
-REGEXP means:

- $ means that we have to touch the end of the string
- [\r\n\t\f\v ] : a space (no sign + or * means we exactly search for one space)
- [0-9] : a digit (+ sign means that we search at 1 to unlimited digits)
- [a-zA-Z] : a letter (* sign means we search at 0 to unlimited letters)

So this REGEXP will always take the last block after last space, because we are searching for a space, 1 or more digits, 0 or more letters, and $ means at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using MySQL.  If so, this comes very close:

```
select (case when substring_index(street, ' ', -1) + 0 > 0
             then substring_index(street, ' ', -1)
        end)
```

If the street ends in 34xyz, then this would put in 34.  For your version with *just* a number:

```
select (case when street regexp ' [0-9]+$'
             then substring_index(street, ' ', -1)
        end)
```

The update would look like this:

```
update t
    set num = substring_index(street, ' ', -1) + 0
    where street regexp ' [0-9]+$';
```

Comment: He says he's using phpMyAdmin, so he should be using MySQL.

Comment: Right Barmar, I'm using Mysql. Thanks Gordon Linoff, I'll try that, can you just update to put that substring in the number column?

Comment: @Jonathan . . . I don't know why I wrote "SQL Server" in the answer.  The syntax is all MySQL in the answer.  SQL Server doesn't even support regular expressions.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, thanks, I'm newbie in MySQL and Regex, and your answer was already a good element of answer, but I can't transform your proposition to update my fields. This request almost worked for filling the number column:UPDATE `map`
SET `number` = substring_index(`street`, ' ', -1)
WHERE `street` IN (SELECT `street` REGEXP  '[0-9]+$'

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff, thanks, your answer was already a good element of answer, but I can't completely transform your proposition to update my fields. This request almost worked for filling the number column:

UPDATE `map`
SET `number` = substring_index(`street`, ' ', -1)
WHERE `street` IN (SELECT `street` REGEXP  '[0-9]+$')

but something is missing, because a field like this:

('Bd de la 2e armée Britannique', '-1') becomes  ('Bd de la 2e armée Britannique', 'Britannique')

and this element should not be affected because the digit is not in the last block of the string

Also, how could I remove this last block  in the street column with another UPDATE request  to finally obtain a truncated string in the field street:

('Rue van Malder 47B', '-1') becomes ('Rue van Malder', '47B')

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the `UPDATE`, etc, I think you need 2 steps to determine that the last word has digits:

```
WHERE street REGEXP "[[:space:]][^[:space:]0-9]+$"
```

Should be TRUE when the last word does *not* contain a digit.  Note:  I am checking for leading, trailing, *or* embedded digit(s).  The statement of the problem, together with the examples, was  was ambiguous in this area.

After that, you can use something like this to extract the last word:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(street, ' ', -1)
```

but that only works for "space", not for general "white space" as in `[[:space:]]`.  *You really need to do the task in a language that has full regexp support.*  (Note: MariaDB is better than MySQL in this area, but still may fall short.)